# Mapping Java beans and Scala case classes to MongoDB objects

Tags: mongodb, javabeans, morphia, case-class, salat

I am currently struggling with this issue here..

In our system, we use **Java beans** *and* **Scala case classes**, and they often contains one another.
So, i am looking for a good solution for how to map these objects to **mongoObjects**, so i can save/load them from the database.

For this, i tried **Morphia**, but unfortunately it won't serialize back from json to object because it cannot construct a case class.

So I tried **Salat**, but this one only works with case classes and not java beans  :(

Do anyone have an idea about how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Salat developer here.

If you want to use Salat, you could convert your Java beans to Scala case classes and annotate the constructor params with `@scala.reflect.BeanProperty` for interoperability with Java (if this is really necessary).